# Are Tcl threads multi process/multi core

Tags: multithreading, tcl

I'm new to using threads in tcl but thought it was a nice way to solve a problem I'm having

I was trying to read through the tcl thread documentation but i can't quite figure out if tcl threads span threads across multiple cpu cores or try to keep all threads within the CPU core from which the master process was started?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken Tcl does not do anything special with it's threads. They're regular POSIX threads so it's up to the OS to decide what to do with them. Most OSes have features for managing threads and processes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tcl's threads are threads as supported by the operating system's standard libraries (e.g., they're normal POSIX threads on Linux and OSX), and so are entirely capable of running over as many cores as the OS allows.

Tcl takes care to limit the use of locks in its implementation as much as possible, so as to make multi-core operation as efficient as possible; this came from experience supporting high-performance application servers in the 1990s, where it turned out that reducing the sharing of resources was a big win as hardware scaled up the number of cores.

It also means that you've got a non-shared memory model based on structured message passing; it scales well, but it was very different to what most programmers knew at the time. It's a little bit more mainstream now because shared-memory parallelism remains annoyingly troublesome on modern hardware.

Comment: @Jonjilla, I have a vague feeling you might have a thought about "green threads" or something like this. If yes, then no, Tcl lets you create a separate Tcl interpreter running on a dedicated physical OS thread (the main interpreter already does this) and then let these interpreters communicate via message passing. So you can have N interpreters running on N underlying OS threads. The OS is then free to schedule these threads however it sees fit--utilizing whatever CPU offers.

Comment: Donal, thanks for the detailed answer.  I wonder if someone should add this into the online documentation for tcl threads.  I couldn't really find this detail anywhere